# Performance issue with returning huge array to worksheet in Excel using VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to automize the classification of notifications within an excel sheet, using VBA.

I think I managed to get a decent performant classification algorithm going, but the problem is returning the classification to the Excel worksheet. The issue is pretty straightforward => the row-count of the excel sheets is around 27k rows.

In the other dimension the array has 3 columns.
I’m using this code to write back the array:

```
Range("M2:O" & UBound(return) + 1).FormulaArray = return
```

where return is the 2D-array.
Is there any way to get a better performing code, or do I simply have to live with it.

Comment: `.FormulaArray` is used for Array formulas which need CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. If you are simply returning the values in the array then you can use `Range("M2:O" & UBound(return) + 1).Value = return`.

Comment: Thanks, that helped! Now it only takes a couple seconds! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[shrivallabha-redij](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8759927/shrivallabha-redij) had the perfect solution, simply using `.Value` instead of `.FormulaArray`.

Reduced the time to a few seconds